# How to blend 2 images with PHP (GD-GD2 Library) like multiply, colorburn, colordodge and others

Tags: php, image, gd, blend, multiplication

I want to blend two images – like multiply, overlay and other blend modes – in PHP with GD library.

My images = İmage1.jpg -- imageblend.jpg or image3.png

Please help me write examples or step by step teach me? I've found some examples but they don't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There aren't many blend modes like that built into GD so you will have to implement them yourself. Unfortunately it will be much slower than a native C implementation but it is possible. Simply load up both images and iterate over the entire base image, applying the blend mode to copy each individual pixel from the top image onto the base image. Add/substract/multiply are really easy and normal alpha blending is fairly simple (although alpha blending is built in as long as you use `imagealphablending` correctly). I'm not aware of the algorithms for color burn or color dodge, but I'm sure a quick search will turn up how to do it. As for overlay, it  turns out that it is actually built into GD if you use `imagelayereffect` before copying the top image.

I pulled this code from [permadi.com](http://permadi.com/blog/2011/08/using-php-gd-to-create-glossy-icons-and-buttons/) for the overlay effect. I've also added some alternate code for a multiply effect to show you how to use PHP for blend mode algorithms. This code assumes that the top image is not larger in either dimension than the base image.

```
<?php
// GD images can be true-color or indexed color. This makes a difference for getting
// and setting pixels so we'll take note of each image.
// Load the base image. For overlays, this should be the template ("overlay.png" in source)
$baseImage = imagecreatefrompng("base.png");
$baseIsTrueColor = imageistruecolor($baseImage);
// Load the image to blend on top.
$topImage = imagecreatefrompng("top.png");
$topIsTrueColor = imageistruecolor($topImage);

// Get image dimensions
$baseWidth  = imagesx($baseImage);
$baseHeight = imagesy($baseImage);
$topWidth   = imagesx($topImage);
$topHeight  = imagesy($topImage);

// Destination X and Y - these values will center $topImage within $baseImage:
$destX = ($baseWidth - $topWidth) / 2;
$destY = ($baseHeight - $topHeight) / 2;

// OVERLAY MODE {
  // This line causes all GD operations to use the overlay algorithm
  // when blending pixels together.
  imagelayereffect($baseImage, IMG_EFFECT_OVERLAY);
  // Blend the top image onto the base image.
  imagecopy(
    $baseImage, // destination
    $topImage, // source
    // destination x and y
    $destX, $destY,
    // x, y, width, and height of the area of the source to copy
    0, 0, $topWidth, $topHeight);
// } OVERLAY

// MULTIPLY MODE {
  // Because we can't just use imagecopy, we have to iterate over all the pixels in
  // the entire image in order to apply the multiply algorithm to each individual pixel.
  // There is probably an easier way to handle true-color vs. indexed color in this
  // section but without testing the code this was the most likely to work. Depending on
  // how `imagecolorsforindex` and `imagecolorclosestalpha` work this section might work
  // a lot simpler.
  for ($x = 0; $x < $topWidth; ++$x) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $topHeight; ++$y) {
      // First get the colors for the base and top pixels.
      $color = imagecolorat($baseImage, $x + $destX, $y + $destY);
      // If the image is true-color, we simply use bitwise operations to separate out
      // red, green, blue, and alpha from the result of imagecolorat above.
      if ($baseIsTrueColor) {
        $baseColor = array(
          'red'   => ($color >> 16) & 0xFF,
          'green' => ($color >> 8) & 0xFF,
          'blue'  => $color & 0xFF,
          'alpha' => ($color & 0x7F000000) >> 24,
        );
      }
      // If the image uses indexed color, we can get the color components by looking up
      // the color index in the image's color table.
      else {
        $baseColor = imagecolorsforindex($baseImage, $color);
      }

      $color = imagecolorat($topImage, $x, $y);
      // If the image is true-color, we simply use bitwise operations to separate out
      // red, green, blue, and alpha from the result of imagecolorat above.
      if ($topIsTrueColor) {
        $topColor = array(
          'red'   => ($color >> 16) & 0xFF,
          'green' => ($color >> 8) & 0xFF,
          'blue'  => $color & 0xFF,
          'alpha' => ($color & 0x7F000000) >> 24,
        );
      }
      // If the image uses indexed color, we can get the color components by looking up
      // the color index in the image's color table.
      else {
        $topColor = imagecolorsforindex($topImage, $color);
      }

      // Now perform the multiply algorithm.
      $destColor = array(
        'red'   => intval($baseColor['red']   * ($topColor['red']   / 255.0)),
        'green' => intval($baseColor['green'] * ($topColor['green'] / 255.0)),
        'blue'  => intval($baseColor['blue']  * ($topColor['blue']  / 255.0)),
        'alpha' => intval($baseColor['alpha'] * ($topColor['alpha'] / 127.0)),
      );

      // Now set the destination pixel.
      $colorIndex = imagecolorallocatealpha($baseImage, $destColor['red'], $destColor['green'], $destColor['blue'], $destColor['alpha']);
      // If we failed to allocate the color, try to find the already allocated color
      // that is closest to what we want.
      if ($colorIndex === FALSE) {
        $colorIndex = imagecolorclosestalpha($baseImage, $destColor['red'], $destColor['green'], $destColor['blue'], $destColor['alpha']);
      }
      // Now that we have a valid color index, set the pixel to that color.
      imagesetpixel($baseImage, $x + $destX, $y + $destY, $colorIndex);
    }
  }
// } MULTIPLY

// Set type of image and send the output
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($baseImage);

// Release memory
imagedestroy($baseImage);
imagedestroy($topImage);     
?>
```

I haven't tested the code so it may not work correctly and it almost certainly is more complex than it needs to be, but it should serve as a good starting point for doing this stuff yourself.

Comment: Thanks **@meustrus**..
I found some algorithms İts Wroten on php clases.
but I dont understand. I want to learn it. step by step

Comment: I added some code to show you how to implement the overlay and multiply blend modes.

Comment: Very thanks @meustrus..
That Code very helpfuly its worked for me..and  your descriptions are very helpfuly for learning this codes..
Take care **meustrus**..

Comment: multiplying works perfect. thank you! someone knows how it works for other blend modes?

Comment: Just did a quick Google search and found this: http://www.deepskycolors.com/archive/2010/04/21/formulas-for-Photoshop-blending-modes.html . So for color burn (1 - (1-Target) / Blend), you'd do this for each color: `'red'   => intval(255.0 - (255.0 - $topColor['red']) / $baseColor['red']))`

Comment: If you want one of the more complex ones, like vivid light, use the ternary operator (bool ? true : false) instead of their weirdness (bool * true + !bool * false). Vivid light, for example `((Blend > 0.5) * (1 - (1-Target) / (2*(Blend-0.5))) +
(Blend <= 0.5) * (Target / (1-2*Blend)))`, would look like: `'red' => intval($baseColor['red'] > 127 ? 255.0 - (255.0 - $topColor['red']) / (2.0 * ($baseColor['red'] - 128)) : $topColor[red'] / (255.0 - 2.0 * $baseColor['red']))`